# Update nil columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Performance belongs_to :user
User has_one :performance
```

`Performance` has many attributes:

> - user_id
> - attr1, default: nil
> - attr2, default: nil
> - attr3, default: nil
> - .....

I want to perform

```
@user.performance.update(
  attr1: 1,
  attr2: 2,
  attr3: 3,
  .....
)
```

but of course it won't go because `@user.performance == nil` by default.
The list of attributes is really long, so I wish to avoid repeating them:

```
unless @user.performance
Performance.create(
  user_id: @user.id,
  attr1: 1,
  attr2: 2,
  attr3: 3,
  .....
) 
else
@user.performance.update(
  attr1: 1,
  attr2: 2,
  attr3: 3,
  .....
)
end
```

Please let me know how can I achieve it. Thanks!

My question is how could I avoid repeating parameter list in my code. I have same params in both `create` and `update` methods.

Comment: For both condition you are getting perfomance object as nil? I mean for if and else section.

Comment: Also add your server log, that will be better to trace error. user6829331

Comment: So whats the exact problem you are facing

Comment: The code snippet you wrote isn't working or what?

Comment: It's working, but imagine I have 10 attributes and don't want to repeat them

Answer (score 0):

You could use first_or_create as referenced here [apidocks](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create)
to get a reference to your object or create it if it doesn't exist. Then update it as necessary.

Comment: Was looking for something like this!

Comment: Always use `build_association` instead of `find_or_create_by` when dealing with associations. which optimizes checking and redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use `@user.build_performance(k:v, k1:v1, ..)`

This will void the earlier or creates the new one and initializes performance record of the user with the latest attributes supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :performance

  def performance
    super || build_performance
  end

end
```

And then:

```
@user.perfomance.update({ 
  attr1: 1,
  attr2: 2,
  attr3: 3,
  # ...
})
```

Update will create the performance in the database if it doesn't exists